# How to load saved data with json.dumps method in django

Tags: python, json, django, django-queryset

[models.py]

```
class History(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True)
    study = models.ForeignKey(Study, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

[views.py]

```
def add_history(request):
    history = History(user=request.user,
                      study=new_study,
                      summary=json.dumps({
                          'field_summary': field_summary,
                          'file_summary': file_summary
                      }))
    history.save()


def chart(request):
    histories = History.objects.filter(summary__icontains='teacher', create_date__gte='2022-01-01', create_date__lte='2022-04-10')\
                                .annotate(teacher=json.loads('summary')['field_summary']['teacher'])\
                                .values('study_name', 'teacher', 'create_date')
    return render(request, 'chart.html', {'histories': histories})
```

[chart.html]

```
{% for h in histories %} {{ h.study_name }},{{ h.teacher }}, {{ h.create_date }} {% endfor %}
```

An error is: JSONDecodeError at /chart/  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).
I want to extract only the teacher value in the summary field. However, an error occurs in the annotate part.

Comment: Please use summary as JSONField in your model. then everythig will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I want to apply it to my current data.

Comment: Annotate works on the _database level_, the `json.loads` whereas will run on the server. Using a `JSONField` is the best solution (You can do some data migrations if you want to keep existing data), if you don't want to go for a `JSONField` then you can loop over all the instances and manually add a value to all of them with the result of `json.loads`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. First of all, I want to go in the direction of not changing field properties, so I would like to try the second you suggested. Where do I need to modify my code to make my second suggestion work?

Comment: Also please **do not** ask the same question multiple times! Please use the [edit] link just below your question to update your post...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm not used to using it, so if I edit it, I thought that my post would not be updated to the latest, so I wrote it again.